# Multiple backbone views referencing one collection

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

I am trying to create my first backbone app and am having some difficulty getting my head around how I am meant to be using views.

What I am trying to do is have a search input that each time its submitted it fetches a collection from the server. I want to have one view control the search input area and listen to events that happen there (a button click in my example) and another view with sub views for displaying the search results. with each new search just prepending the results into the search area.

the individual results will have other methods on them (such as looking up date or time that they where entered etc).

I have a model and collection defined like this:

```
SearchResult = Backbone.model.extend({
    defaults: {
        title: null,
        text: null
    }
});

SearchResults = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: SearchResult,
    initialize: function(query){
        this.query = query;
        this.fetch();
    },
    url: function() {
        return '/search/' + this.query()
    }
});
```

In my views I have one view that represents the search input are:

```
var SearchView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#search'),
    events: {
        'click button': 'doSearch' 
    },
    doSearch: function() {
        console.log('starting new search');
        var resultSet = new SearchResults($('input[type=text]', this.el).val());
        var resultSetView = new ResultView(resultSet); 
    }
});

var searchView = new SearchView();

var ResultSetView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#search'),
    initialize: function(resultSet) {
        this.collection = resultSet;
        this.render();
    },
    render: function() {
        _(this.collection.models).each(function(result) {
            var resultView = new ResultView({model:result});
        }, this);
    }
});

var ResultView = Backbone.view.extend({
     tagName: 'div',
     model: SearchResult,
     initialize: function() {
         this.render();
     },
     render: function(){ 
         $(this.el).append(this.model.get(title) + '<br>' + this.model.get('text'));
     }
});
```

and my html looks roughly like this:

```
<body>
<div id="search">
    <input type="text">
    <button>submit</button>
</div>
<div id="results">

</div>

</body>
```

In my code it gets as far as `console.log('starting new search');` but no ajax calls are made to the server from the initialize method of the ResultSetView collection.

Am I designing this right or is there a better way to do this. I think because the two views bind to different dom elements I should not be instantiating one view from within another. Any advice is appreciated and if I need to state this clearer please let me know and I will do my best to rephrase the question.

Comment: Do you see any JS errors being thrown?
Also, the ajax calls would be made on the initialization of your `SearchResults` `Collection`, since that is where you tell it to do the fetching.

Comment: yeah it will log to the console but no ajax request will take place. Also no js errors.

Comment: Beware that with the actual implementation the `ResultView` instances will be created but their `render` result will not be added to the `SearchView.$el`.

Comment: Does the code arrive to `SearchResults.initialize()`? can you put a `console.log` before the `this.fetch()`?

Comment: I see a typo here `SearchResult = Backbone.model.extend({ ...`

Comment: Another typo here `var ResultView = Backbone.view.extend({ ...`

Comment: Another typo here `return '/search/' + this.query()` due `this.query` is not a function... so you should check again your console looking for JS errors.

Comment: Another typo here `this.model.get(title)` :/

Comment: Sorry about all the typos, The actual code I am using is quite a bit more complicated than this so I just write a slimmed down version here of what I have. I will rewrite the op now.

Comment: Are you using Chrome to test it?

Comment: Sorry guys I realise I asked this question in an utterly horrible and unwell thought out way. I have since been hitting the docs hard and have figured out I was approaching the whole problem wrongly. Thanks to anyone who left an answer or a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some problems (possibly not the only ones):

- Your *SearchView* isn't bound to the collection *reset* event; as written it's going to attempt to render immediately, while the collection is still empty.
- *SearchView* instantiates the single view *ResultView* when presumably it should instantiate the composite view *ResultSetView*.
- You're passing a parameter to the *SearchResults* collection's constructor, but that's not the correct way to use it.  See the [documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-constructor) on this point.

Comment: SearchView probably doesn't need to listen to the reset event as much as ResultSetView, but good call on your other comments.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't told your `ResultSetView` to listen to any events on the collection.  "fetch" is asynchronous.  When completed successfully, it will send a "reset" event.  Your view needs to listen for that event and then do whatever it needs to do (like render) on that event.

Answer (score 0):

After fixing all the *typos* in your example code I have a [working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fguillen/KXWz9/).

You see like after clicking in the button an AJAX call is done. Of course the response is an error but this is not the point.

So my conclusion is that your problem is in another part of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Among some syntax issues, the most probable problem to me that I see in your code is a race condition. In your views, you're making an assumption that the fetch has already retrieved the data and you're executing your views render methods. For really fast operations, that might be valid, but it gives you no way of truly knowing that the data exists. The way to deal with this is as others have suggested: You need to listen for the collection's reset event; however, you also have to control "when" the fetch occurs, and so it's best to do the fetch only when you need it - calling fetch within the search view. I did a bit of restructuring of your collection and search view:

```
var SearchResults = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: SearchResult,
    execSearch : function(query) {
        this.url = '/search/' + query;
        this.fetch();
    }
});

var SearchView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#search'),
    initialize : function() {
        this.collection = new SearchResults();
        //listen for the reset
        this.collection.on('reset',this.displayResults,this);
    },
    events: {
        'click button': 'doSearch' 
    },
    /**
    * Do search executes the search
    */
    doSearch: function() {
        console.log('starting new search');
        //Set the search params and do the fetch.
        //Since we're listening to the 'reset' event, 
        //displayResults will execute. 
        this.collection.execSearch($('input[type=text]', this.el).val());
    },
    /**
    * displayResults sets up the views. Since we know that the
    * data has been fetched, just pass the collection, and parse it
    */
    displayResults : function() {
        new ResultSetView({
            collection : this.collection
        });
    }
});
```

Notice that I only created the collection once. That's all you need since you're using the same collection class to execute your searches. Subsequent searches only need to change the url. This is better memory management and a bit cleaner than instantiating a new collection for each search.

I didn't work further on your display views. However, you might consider sticking to the convention of passing hashes to Backbone objects. For instance, in your original code, you passed 'resultSet' as a formal parameter. However, the convention is to pass the collection to a view in the form: new View({collection: resultSet}); I realize that that's a bit nitpicky, but following the conventions improves the readability of your code. Also, you ensure that you're passing things in the way that the Backbone objects expect.